# List files causing high server loads using cPanel, serverside code or third-party software?

Tags: share

Is there an extension for cPanel, an application, or server-side script that can simply output the currently used resources on my server, pointing out the ones causing temporary high loads so they can be taken down or fixed as issues arise?

Is there a way of determining if files causing high server load are my own on a shared serer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
watch -d -n <interval> top -b -n 1
```

if you have a better idea of what kind of load is being caused (i.e., disk, cpu, memory, etc...), you can generally use watch + one of the stat commands to narrow it down like:

```
watch -d -n 2 vmstat -a
```